# Recurring Delimiter in java with broken message to an array

Tags: java, arrays, json, regex, string

I have a String:

```
String received = "28,gZrate:-1.48},
{gXrate:9.10,gYrate:-0.69,gZrate:-1.50},        
{gXrate:9.22,gYrate:0.54,gZrate:-1.67},     
{gXrate:9.20,gYrate:-2.40,gZrate:-1.65},{gXrate:9.02" ;
```

I need this string to be in an array like this:

```
["gXrate:9.10,gYrate:-0.69,gZrate:-1.50","gXrate:9.22,gYrate:0.54,gZrate:-1.67","gXrate:9.20,gYrate:-2.40,gZrate:-1.65"]
```

neglecting the broken part of received string at the beginning and end 
i.e.

```
28,gZrate:-1.48}

{gXrate:9.02 ;
```

also to note at times string may not be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String received = "28,gZrate:-1.48},{gXrate:9.10,gYrate:-0.69,gZrate:-1.50},";
       received += "{gXrate:9.22,gYrate:0.54,gZrate:-1.67},";
       received += "{gXrate:9.20,gYrate:-2.40,gZrate:-1.65},{gXrate:9.02";
String pattern = "\\{(.*?)\\},?";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
boolean first = true;

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(received);
while (m.find()) {
    if (!first) {
        sb.append(",");
    }
    first = false;
    sb.append("\"" + m.group(1) + "\"");
}
sb.append("]");
System.out.println(sb);
```

**Output:**

```
["gXrate:9.10,gYrate:-0.69,gZrate:-1.50","gXrate:9.22,gYrate:0.54,gZrate:-1.67","gXrate:9.20,gYrate:-2.40,gZrate:-1.65"]
```

Here is a demo which shows that the above code works for both the broken and balanced cases:

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> nonBrokenStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    String received = "28,gZrate:-1.48},{gXrate:9.10,gYrate:-0.69,gZrate:-1.50}, {gXrate:9.22,gYrate:0.54,gZrate:-1.67}, {gXrate:9.20,gYrate:-2.40,gZrate:-1.65},{gXrate:9.02";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]+)\\}").matcher(received);
    while(m.find()) {
      nonBrokenStrings.add(m.group(1));
    }
    String[] nonBrokenStringsArr = nonBrokenStrings.toArray(new String[nonBrokenStrings.size()]);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(nonBrokenStringsArr));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[gXrate:9.10,gYrate:-0.69,gZrate:-1.50, gXrate:9.22,gYrate:0.54,gZrate:-1.67, gXrate:9.20,gYrate:-2.40,gZrate:-1.65]
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/HJWC/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String formatToArrayStr(String input){
    String regex="\\{([^}]+)\\}";
    Matcher m=Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder().append("[");
    while(m.find()){
        result.append("\"").append(m.group(1)).append("\"").append(",");
    }       
    result=(result.lastIndexOf(",")>=0?result.deleteCharAt(result.length()-1):result).append("]");
    return result.toString();
}
```

also,you can write like below:

```
public static String formatToArrayStr(String input){
    Matcher m=Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]+)\\}").matcher(input);
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(m.find()){
        result.add("\""+m.group(1)+"\"");
    }       
    return result.toString();
}
```

Output

```
["gXrate:9.10,gYrate:-0.69,gZrate:-1.50","gXrate:9.22,gYrate:0.54,gZrate:-1.67","gXrate:9.20,gYrate:-2.40,gZrate:-1.65"]
```